# Unable to read Request.Form variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am unable to read request.form name/value pairs from a very simple external page posting to a simple aspx page.  This is working in other environments but not my local development environment.  I'm using VS2013 Update 4.  Is there some security setting in web.config preventing values to be posted?  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my sending page (sender.html):

```
<html>
<body>
    Post values to receiver.aspx page  
    <form action="http://localhost:61034/receiver.aspx" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded ">

        <input name="Field1" type="text" value="1" id="Field1" /><br />
        <input name="Field2" type="text" value="some text information here" id="Field2" /><br />

        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my receiving page (receiver.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="receiver.aspx.cs" Inherits="receiver"  %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%
            string f1 = Request.Form["Field1"];
            string f2 = Request.Form["Field2"];
            Response.Write("Field1= " + f1 );
            Response.Write("<br>Field2= " + f2);

        %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should have added that the request.form values always return null/empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpContext.Current` in your code.

```
string f1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Field1"];
string f2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Field2"];
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Field1= " + f1 );
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br>Field2= " + f2);
```

You can also use Import directive as below

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.MyNamespace" %>
```

or use your root web.config file as below

```
<system.web>    
<pages>
   <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System" />
      <add namespace="System.Collections" />
      <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
      <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
      <add namespace="System.Text" />
      <!-- etc -->
   </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I have updated the code in my receiving page to use httpcontext and added the namepsaces to the web.config file as suggested but still having the same issue.  Any other ideas?  I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have a small value set as max request length limit. You should check your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
</system.web>
```

`maxRequestLength` value is in KB. Or you can set it only for your page:

```
<location path="receiver.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

10240 means 10Mb.

Also, make sure that `Request Validation` is disabled in your aspx page:

```
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: I added <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" /> to the web.config and have the same issue.  Could this have anything to do with security?  that is, the app not allowing values to be posted to it from an external source?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an info about `Request Validation`. Can you also check this?

Comment: I set this and still get null values from the post: '<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="receiver2.aspx.cs" Inherits="receiver2" validateRequest="false" %>

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue. I tested it in both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 update 4. It is working perfectly for me.

[image]

Here is the code

**sender**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Post values to receiver.aspx page
    <form action="http://localhost:50226/receiver.aspx" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded ">

        <input name="Field1" type="text" value="1" id="Field1" /><br />
        <input name="Field2" type="text" value="some text information here" id="Field2" /><br />

        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**receiver**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="receiver.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsSample._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%
            string f1 = Request.Form["Field1"];
            string f2 = Request.Form["Field2"];
            Response.Write("Field1= " + f1 );
            Response.Write("<br>Field2= " + f2);

        %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Only difference I can see is `Inherits="WebFormsSample._Default"`I am not sure if it is any issue.

Comment: I copied your code line for line for both pages and still no luck.  This has to be an environment issue with Visual Studio.  I can't post web.config here as it is too large.  If there is a particular section I can provide that would shed some light, let me know.